# How to find percentages of values in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I use following query to find out percentage of winning by Hero in games:

```
SELECT Hero, (COUNT(*) * g.games) AS p
FROM gamestatistics
JOIN (
SELECT 100/COUNT(*) AS games
FROM gamestatistics
) AS g
WHERE PointEarned>0
GROUP BY Hero
ORDER BY p DESC
```

But this gives me percent for ALL games. And I want  to know

> `percentage(for Hero)=(Won games by this player)/(Played games by this hero)`

instead of

> percentage(for Hero)=(Won games by this player)/(All games)
>   Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just add `WHERE Hero = whatever` after your `WHERE PointEarned>0` ?

Comment: Do not divide by count(*), it could be zero.

Comment: But this will give me information only for 1 hero and I need for all of them. And this will not change that it will divide on all games, not games where this hero played

Comment: @MycRub count(*) will never be 0, 0 means no rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  hero, AVG(pointEarned > 0) p
FROM    gamestatistics
GROUP BY
        hero
ORDER BY
        p DESC
```

Comment: @tonven I fail to see how this can return a percentage. I can't even compile it

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: `AVG` accepts `NUMERIC` which `BOOLEAN` gets autocast into. `pointEarned > 0` yields `1` or `0` (or `NULL` if the field is nullable).

Comment: very smart solution - congrats

Comment: I appologize i had not seen the mysql tag. I never understood that. I tested on sql server

Comment: @t-clausen.dk well I suppose on SQL server we can do `avg(case when gc.PointEarned > 0 then 1 else 0 end)`

Comment: @RomanPekar - yes, you could do that, but you would be getting a wrong result in most cases (except at 100 % and 0 %). since average of 1 and 0 will be 0 since it works with integers unless specified as 1.0 or better 100.0 since we are operating in percent

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select
   gc.Hero,
   sum(case when gc.PointEarned > 0 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*) as p
from gamestatistics as gc
group by by gc.Hero
order by p desc
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! Can you explain how it works inside of sum?

Comment: well `sum` just sums values for each row. For that case you just need to add 1 if game was won and 0 if it wasn't. you can just use a `case` statement for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `count(HERO)` in place of `count(*)` as I am thinking its not able to perform the group by properly.

```
  SELECT Hero, (COUNT(HERO) * g.games) AS p
  FROM gamestatistics
  JOIN (
        SELECT 100/COUNT(*) AS games
        FROM gamestatistics
  ) AS g
  WHERE PointEarned>0
  GROUP BY Hero
  ORDER BY p DESC;
```

EDIT: I believe you wanted `sum of PointsEarned` to be divided by count. In that case the query is little changed as below:

```
SELECT Hero, (SUM(case when PointEarned <1 then 0 else 1 end)*100/count(HERO)) AS p
FROM gamestatistics
GROUP BY Hero
ORDER BY p DESC;
```

Comment: @Tonven: Sorry I forgot to put `COUNT(HERO)` in the query. Try the updated query.

Comment: @Tonven: I added another query in the answer

Comment: @Tonven I realized we can't use `IF-THEN-ELSE` in select. Updated the query.

Comment: Now it returns 100 percents for all players

Comment: @Tonven Now I got the root problem.  There is no need of `WHERE` clause. I believe you are trying to calculate the percentage as: `count all games where points >0/total games*100`. Just to make data points, if HERO has `3,4,9,30,0,6,1,0` points i.e. 6 out of 8 non zero points, then his percentage is : 75%, right?

Comment: @Tonven: Good. Please don't forget to accept the answer, if you like it.